# A closed-form for $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1-\operatorname{sinc}(n^{-1}))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form

I'm trying to find a closed form of $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1-\operatorname{sinc}(n^{-1})),$$but I have no experience in constructing a closed form before. Could anyone give me some help? The convergence is assured due to $1-\operatorname{sinc}(n^{-1})=O(n^{-2}), n\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: If you type `3\text{sinc}x` you will see $3\text{sinc}x$, whereas if you type `3\operatorname{sinc}x` you will see $3\operatorname{sinc}x,$ and that is part of the reason why the latter usage is standard. Notice also that the amount of space to the right of $\operatorname{sinc}$ differs in the following: $\operatorname{sinc}x$ versus $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$, both of which use `\operatorname{sinc}`, so that's another part of the reason. I edited this question accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy Thanks for correcting!

Comment: @Oliver Diaz That gives an infinite sum of the special values of Riemman function, but still not a closed form.

Comment: Have you any reason to expect that there is a closed form?

Comment: A generalization might be apropos: maybe asking questions about the $L$(ish)-function defined by the analytic continuation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\mathrm{sinc}(n^{-s})\right)$ might be informative (in lieu of a closed form)

Comment: this came out: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14070 /Arithmetic and Analysis of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{x}{n}$/ by Roger Gay, Ahmed Sebbar